# Missmatching shapes in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to do a multivariate linear regression and I am having some issues. Namely, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (3,) for Tensor 'X:0', which has shape '(1, 3)'
```

I have 3 feature variables, which I call trainX and 1 label, which I call trainY. Their shapes are the following (they are numpy arrays):

```
trainX.shape:
(2500, 3)
trainY.shape:
(2500,)
```

The following piece of code defines the tensors that I use to compute the model:

```
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float", [1, 3], name="X")
Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float", [1], name="Y")

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3, 1]), name="W")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name="b")
```

I calculate the predicted label and the cost function and the optimizer by doing:

```
predicted_y = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(predicted_y-Y, 2)) / (2 * n)
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

I am getting the error in the tensor-flow session, namely in the following piece of code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (_x, _y) in zip(trainX, trainY):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: _x, Y: _y})
        if (epoch + 1) % 100 == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: trainX, Y: trainY})
            print("Epoch", (epoch + 1), ": cost =", c, "W =", sess.run(W), "b =", sess.run(b))
    # Storing necessary values to be used outside the Session
    training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: trainX, Y: trainY})
    weight = sess.run(W)
    bias = sess.run(b)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `_x` is a vector with 3 elements, while `X` expects a matrix with 1 line and 3 columns. One possible solution would be to reshape `_x`:

```
_x = np.reshape(_x, [1, 3])
```

Another possibility would be to change the placeholder to the input shape:

```
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float", [3], name="X")
```

Often one wants to train on more than one example. In this case, you may want to define the placeholders to allow any number of inputs:

```
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float", [None, 3], name="X")
Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float", [None], name="Y")
```

Then we could for example we use batches of 100:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for i in range(trainX.shape[0] % 100):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: trainX[i*100:(i+1)*100, ...], Y: trainY[i*100:(i+1)*100]})
```

Comment: Did you make a typo on your first possibility? Where should I put that? Shouldn't it be trainX = np.reshape(trainX, [1,3)?

Comment: Your second possibility also doesn't work, namely: "ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [3], [3,1]."

Comment: For the first possibility, you cannot reshape trainX to [1,3] because reshaping trainX into [1,3] requires that trainX has only three numbers in it (arranged in whatever configuration of rows and columns) while trainX has 3*2500 numbers in it. The line I suggested reshapes one row of trainX at a time, so it inside the for loop iterating over `(_x, _y)` before `sess.run`.

Comment: For the second possibility, you are right, I didn't consider the cascading effects of this change. To make it work one would need to change `W` to `W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]), name="W")` and `predicted_y` to `predicted_y = tf.multiply(X, W) + b`